# Как расширить MainActivity от двух классов сразу FragmentActivity и AppCompatActivity?

Tags: java, android

Сейчас я расширяю от FragmentActivity вот так:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

// ...

}
```

Но при этом не срабатывает `onCreateOptionsMenu()` и у меня отсутствует *action bar* с иконкой меню.

Как мне одновременно расшириться от `AppCompatActivity` чтобы появилось меню?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Никак в Java. Замените extends FragmentActivity на AppCompatActivity

Comment: Спасибо! Не понятно только зачем ведущий курса заменял AppCompatActivity на FragmentActivity если работа с фрагментом и так проходит нормально.